# Query Two Databases with a Map table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been pulling my hair out over this one...and Im fairly sure its strait forward enough..but I cant find the answer.

What Im trying to do is to draw information from two tables.  Im fairly new to JOIN.  I guess as a practical example, lets say I have a database of books (id,title,author,edition,year).  Then I have a database of classes (id,subject,teacher).  Some classes will use the same book.  So, I created a map table as described here:

Select-Query/Joinamanytomanymaptable.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0040_Select-Query/Joinamanytomanymaptable.htm

I created a table called ClassBook Where the class id (ClassID) was listed in one column and book id (BookID) in the other.

what I want is to draw the BOOK information based on the class.  So if the class id is 3, I want all the books associated with that class and their information.  Below is an example of what Im querying:

SELECT * FROM ClassBook
    JOIN books
       ON ClassID=3

From this query, If the Class id (3) is in the table (ClassBook) 8 times, it will output EVERY book and its information 8 times.  All I want is the books associated with class id 3 and their information.  Any help is WAY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM class
JOIN ClassBook on class.id = ClassBook.ClassID
JOIN books on ClassBook.BookID = books.id
WHERE Class.ID = 3;
```

That's the format you'll use for linking everything together. Note that the `on` clause is usually placed describing the criteria that relates the tables being joined. The `where` clause is for limiting the records selected.

Comment: I'll love ya forever =)  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT books.* FROM ClassBook CB
JOIN books ON  CB.bookid=Books.id
WHERE cb.ClassID=3
```

The join will create a larger "result" of all columns from the class book table and all columns from the book table that share the same book Id number...   The WHERE clause then only shows results from that larger result those books used in ClassID=3.   The books.* syntax only shows the columns from the books table,  a * by itself would show all columns from both tables.